# Program for finding all Palindrome words just outputs first two words

Tags: java, palindrome

I wrote this program to check for all Palindrome words in a sentence but for some reason it just outputs the first two palindrome words of the sentence. This is what I have tried:

```
import java.util.*;
public class palin {
    boolean checkPalin(String st){
        int l = st.length();
        String str ="";
        for(int i=l-1;i>=0;i--) {
            char ch = st.charAt(i);
            str = str + Character.toString(ch);
        }
        if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(st)==true){
            return(true);
        }
        else {
            return(false);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the string");
        String st = sc.nextLine();
        palin ob = new palin();
        StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(st);
        System.out.println(str.countTokens());
        for(int j=1;j<=str.countTokens();j++){
            String st1 = str.nextToken();
            boolean b = ob.checkPalin(st1);
            if (b==true){
                System.out.print(st1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please help me with it?

Comment: Please note: Java and Javascript are not the same language, in the same way that Austria and Australia are not the same country.

Answer (score 0):

As you pull Tokens from the `StringTokenizer`, `str.countTokens()` is changing dynamically, making your `for` loop end earlier than expected.  See working example here:

https://repl.it/@timmy_i_chen/LongtermSlimyDromedary